# OAuth2RestTemplate with prefetched JWT token

Tags: jwt, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate, oauth-2.0

JWT OAuth2 Token is prefetched from Spring Auth Server and stored in Redis Storage.

I don't want to request access token in `OAuth2RestTemplate` and I want to use my JWT Token for requests.

Can I do it with `OAuth2RestTemplate` or I should use usual `RestTemplate`?

Comment: Please add some details to this question.  Is the JWT a symantic OAuth2 token such that an authorization header would have the form `Authorization:  Bearer <JWT with Oauth2 payload>` or is the JWT meant to be inspected for an access token as part of a different authoriazation scheme which is then transformed or ... ?

Comment: JWT is OAuth2 token in authorisation header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/docs/oauth2.md) is useful here, basically the two sections:  JWT Tokens and Accessing Protected Resources:

> JWT Tokens
>
> To use JWT tokens you need a JwtTokenStore in your Authorization
>   Server. The Resource Server also needs to be able to decode the tokens
>   so the JwtTokenStore has a dependency on a JwtAccessTokenConverter,
>   and the same implementation is needed by both the Authorization Server
>   and the Resource Server. The tokens are signed by default, and the
>   Resource Server also has to be able to verify the signature, so it
>   either needs the same symmetric (signing) key as the Authorization
>   Server (shared secret, or symmetric key), or it needs the public key
>   (verifier key) that matches the private key (signing key) in the
>   Authorization Server (public-private or asymmetric key). The public
>   key (if available) is exposed by the Authorization Server on the
>   /oauth/token_key endpoint, which is secure by default with access rule
>   "denyAll()". You can open it up by injecting a standard SpEL
>   expression into the AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer (e.g.
>   "permitAll()" is probably adequate since it is a public key).
>
> To use the JwtTokenStore you need "spring-security-jwt" on your
>   classpath (you can find it in the same github repository as Spring
>   OAuth but with a different release cycle).
>
> Accessing Protected Resources
>
> Once you've supplied all the configuration for the resources, you can
>   now access those resources. The suggested method for accessing those
>   resources is by using the RestTemplate introduced in Spring 3. OAuth
>   for Spring Security has provided an extension of RestTemplate that
>   only needs to be supplied an instance of
>   OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails.

This basically means to me that you'll use the same spring-security-jwt JwtAccessTokenConverter class in both the authorization server and the resource server and that the token services in each need to be setup with the JwtTokenStore().  The extension to the RestTemplate class they're referring to is the OAuth2RestTemplate from spring-security-oauth2.  You'd use it in your resource server with it's JWT smarts being provided by an equivalent token recognizer.

Because the spring-security-oauth2 code is already set up to handle JWT tokens, you just need to provide a few key pieces and let the framework do the heavy lifting of inspecting the token and putting the security into scope for each protected resource.

As it would happen, someone's posted a nice example of this which goes into detail:  [baeldung spring-security-oauth-jwt example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt) and here:  [github project of the same](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth) including how one could provide a more customized JWT (claims/payload).